# Deeplink navigation with Jetpack Compose using nested graphs

Tags: android, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a large project and to make navigation simpler I have multiple nested graphs (NavHosts). I'm facing some problems to define proper way to handle deep-linking for multiple nested graphs approach.

Example:
Root NavHost

```
NavHost(
        navController = rootNavController,
        startDestination = route,
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.LandingView.route) {
            LandingScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screens.HomeView.route) {
            HomeScreen() // Home screen contains nested NavHost (nested graph)
        }}
```

Example Home NavHost

```
NavHost(
        navController = homeNavControlle,
        startDestination = route,
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.ProfileDetails.route) {
            ProfileDetailsScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screens.ProductDetails.route) {
            ProductDetailsScreen()
        }}
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks) to handle deep-link I need to add **deepLinks** param to composable that is responsible for handling this deep-link. In my case it's ProfileDetailsScreen composable.

After adding this param code looks like this:

```
            NavHost(navController = homeNavController,
        startDestination = route,
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.ProfileDetails.route) {
            ProfileDetailsScreen()
        }
        composable(
        route = Screens.ProductDetails.route, 
        deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "app://profile/details?{profileId}"
        })
        ) {
            ProductDetailsScreen()
        }
```

}

Unfortunately this code does not work because nested graph does not see deep-link.
When I add the same lines of code (deepLinks param) to root NavHost it starts working.

```
NavHost(
        navController = rootNavController,
        startDestination = route,
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.LandingView.route) {
            LandingScreen()
        }
        composable(
        route = Screens.HomeView.route, 
        deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "app://profile/details?{profileId}"
        })
        ) {
            HomeScreen() // Home screen contains nested NavHost (nested graph)
```

}

Having this code causes other navigation problem for the following scenario.

**Root Graph** (Landing Screen **->** Home Screen)

**Home Graph** (Home Screen **->** Profile Details Screen)

When user taps on deep-link that contains profile ID, it's being redirected to Profile Details Screen (having Landing Screen and Home Screen in back stack).

When user goes back to Home Screen and then Back to Landing Screen and then goes to Home screen again (not via deep-link) user is redirected to Profile Details screen instead because RootNav graph still has deep-link in back stack entry.

Is there any solutions to solve this problem or advices how to handle dee-linking with nested graphs in a better way?

Comment: You probably want to use the navigation() extension function in order to build nested navigation graphs. Having a NavHost inside another NavHost is not a common practice (it's not documented anywhere)

Comment: Hi @DerekK. I think you are referring this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav, 
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the way to implement nested navigation with deeplink support.

Comment: Thanks @DerekK. I'll try to update my code using recommended approach. Do you want to post your answer so I could highlight it?

Comment: Everything is working fine when I have only 1 NavHost but when I need to create another one (for BottomNavigation as example) it does not work.